# java- index out of range

Tags: java, string

I was asked to write the method of "indexOf" for `String`. The method gets a string and a sub string. and returns the index at which the substring appears, if it does at all.

But I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 115
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Strings.substring(Strings.java:132)
    at Strings.indexOf(Strings.java:153)
    at Strings.main(Strings.java:70)
```

This is my code:

```
    //Calling Int indexOf() method:
    //getting a new string and a substring from the user
    System.out.println("Please enter a new string");
    str4 = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter a new substring");
    str4Sub = scan.nextLine();

    int test = indexOf(str4, str4Sub);
    if (test != -1){
            System.out.println("Your substring appeared first on place "
                    + indexOf(str4, str4Sub) + "on your string");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, your substring doesnt appear in "
                + "the given string");

    }


}



/*
 * Tests whether the two given string are the same.
 * Returns true if the strings are equal,false otherwise. 
 */

public static boolean isEqual(String s1, String s2){

    int str1_length = s1.length(); //saves the length of the first string
    int str2_length = s2.length();; //saves the length of the first string
    boolean equal = true;
    int i = 0;

    //checking whether the length of both strings is the same
    if (str1_length == str2_length) {
        while (i != str1_length){
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i)){ //checking if the chars at 
                //places i on both strings are 
                //the same
                i++;
                equal = true;
            }
            else{
                equal = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        equal = false;
    }
    return equal;
}



/*
 * Returns a new substring of string 'S',from place 'index' and in length 
 * of length' 
 * Returns String, newStr
 */

public static String substring(String s, int index, int length){
    String newStr = ""; //will save the new string returned

    //copying the new string in length of the given length  
    while (length != 0){
        newStr += s.charAt(index);
        index++;
        length--; 
    }
    return newStr;
}


/*
 *Returns the index of the first appearance within the string s
 *of the substring sub.
 *Returns Integer, i.  
 */

public static int indexOf(String s, String sub){

    int i = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    String strTmp = "";

    while (i < s.length() && ( (s.length() - i )> sub.length() ) ){
        strTmp = substring(s, s.charAt(i), sub.length());
        System.out.println(strTmp);

        if (isEqual(strTmp, sub)){
            flag = true;
            break;

        }
        else{
            i++;    
            flag = false;
        }
    }   

    if (!flag){
        i = -1;
        return i;
    }
    else{
        return i;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: May I suggest you to use a debugger ?

Comment: you are attempting to access index 115 on a String that is less than 116 characters long. It's happening on line 70 of your code.

Comment: what do you purpose with this method? May be we can recommend better one.

Comment: @MadConan - Line 132, more likely - line 70 is just where the method throwing the exception is called inside of `main`.

Comment: Some research on SO or reading some JDK docs would have helped you as well.

Comment: The error is in your `substring` method not your `indexOf` method

Comment: That's not all of your code, though, is it?  The error is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: Why not just use the actual, built-in String.indexOf()? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar _"we were asked to write the method of "indexOf" for string"_ Sounds like a HW =)

Comment: well if you could offer a better one ill gladly look into it! :)) @mmc18

Comment: @ZouZou smarter, not harder. If I gave a student this assignment and they just wrote a wrapper method, 100% because you did the proper research instead of just jumping in and writing it yourself. 96% of programming is research.

Comment: @Danny i dont understand. my substring method works fine. but just in case, i added it to the original msg.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar unfortunately not all teachers think that way.

Comment: guys, could you pls help me, i dont know how to make it right.

Comment: OP - you still haven't given us all of your code.  We can't help you if you don't show us the code where the bug is; and if you don't know where the bug is, then showing us a little bit of the code at the time isn't very useful.  I'm guessing it's in your `main` method, but that's a guess only.  You need to show us the whole code, or we may as well all just go home.

Comment: @user2953423 why are you passing `s.charAt(i)` as the 2nd parameter to your substring method. Don't you mean to pass just `i`? Also in your substring method you do no range checking, `index` can be a larger number than `s.length()`. That is the reason you are getting the exception.

Comment: ok i added now all my code i how its ok now

Answer (score 0):

In `indexOf`, you wrote

```
 strTmp = substring(s, s.charAt(i), sub.length());
```

where the second parameter to `substring` is actually an `int`.  So the character at position `i` of `s` gets converted to an `int` when it is passed to this method.  That's going to be a bigger number than you expected.  Depending on what the character is, and how long the `String` is, it's very likely to give you a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You should change that line to read

```
 strTmp = substring(s, i, sub.length());
```